# Split a list in half

Tags: list, prolog

I need to define divide so that List `[1,2,3,4,5]` divides into:

```
a = [1,2,3}

b = [4,5]
```

I'm getting an error that says `"Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"`, and I don't know enough about the language to figure out what my problem is, or if my design is even right. Any guidance would be appreciated.

So here's what I have so far:

```
append([],L2,L2).
append([H|T],L2,[H|L3]) :- append(T,L2,L3).

lengthIs([],N).
lengthIs([H|T],N) :- lengthIs(T,M), N is M+1.

divide([],[],[]).
divide([H|T],L2,L3) :-
   (  lengthIs(L2, M) < lengthIs(L1,N)/2
   -> divide(T, append(L2, H, X), L3)
   ;  divide(T, L2, append(L3,H,Y))
   ).
```

Comment: The solution you checked as answer fails for `div([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[4,5]).`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's give the predicate a more relational name: `list_half_half/3`

```
list_half_half(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
   length(Xs, N),
   H is N - N // 2,
   length(Ys, H),
   append(Ys, Zs, Xs).
```

`length/2` and `append/3` are predefined in practically all recent Prologs.

This is GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- append(L,_,[a,b,c,d]), list_half_half(L,H1,H2).

H1 = []
H2 = []
L = [] ? ;

H1 = [a]
H2 = []
L = [a] ? ;

H1 = [a]
H2 = [b]
L = [a,b] ? ;

H1 = [a,b]
H2 = [c]
L = [a,b,c] ? ;

H1 = [a,b]
H2 = [c,d]
L = [a,b,c,d]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the most efficient solution conforming to your specification for most Prolog implementations:

```
divide(L, A, B) :-
    divide1(L, L, A, B).

divide1([], L, [], L).
divide1([_|T], [H|L], [H|A], B) :-
    divide2(T, L, A, B).

divide2([], L, [], L).
divide2([_|T], L, A, B) :-
    divide1(T, L, A, B).
```

If you don't mind which elements go into the sublists as far as they are of similar length (as in the solution from Konstantin Weitz post), then you can use :

```
divide([], [], []).
divide([H|T], [H|A], B) :- divide(T, B, A).
```

Comment: Your solution terminates if the first or the second list's length is known. So `divide(L,A,B) terminates_if bound(L) ; bound(A).` But it still does not terminate for `divide(L,A,[]).` Two answers are expected here! `L = [], A = [] ; L = [X], A = [X]`

Comment: yes, that predicate is expected to be used as `divide(+, -, -)`.

Comment: You are better than `+, -, -` already! There is `divide(L,[a],H)` and even `divide([a|_],[b|_],_)` nicely terminates.

Comment: yes, I know, but this is just by coincidence, not because the predicate was designed to handle that case and it leaves a choice point behind so even if it terminates it does it suboptimally.

Comment: I cannot see the choicepoint you are mentioning. It's perfect for `+,-,-` and `-,+,-`

Comment: I have tested it on SWI-Prolog (though not with one of the newer versions implementing JIT indexing) and `divide(L, [a], H)` leaves a choice point there.

Comment: `divide(L,[a],H)` has to produce two answers! After the second answer, no choice point is left in recent versions. But you are right: Older non-JIT indexing versions leave a choicepoint.

Answer (score 4):

append is a pre-defined predicate, so that might be the issue: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Lists#The_append_predicate

You also never defined 'N' in lengthIs - you need to set the empty list as 0, not N/
There's likely also a size function

The underscore tells Prolog we don't care about that bit in that predicate definition.

Something like this should work

```
divide(L1,L2,L3):- append(L2,L3,L1), 
                   samesize(L2,L3).
divide(L1,L2,L3):- append(L2,L3,L1), 
                   onebigger(L2,L3).
samesize(A,B):-    size(A,N),
                   size(B,N).
onebigger(A,[_|T]):-   size(A,N), 
                   size(T,N).
size([],0).
size([H|T],N):-    size(T,M+1).
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely the effect of this code (`lengthIs(L2, M) < lengthIs(L1,N)/2 -> ...`) isn't what you expect: it doesn't compare numbers, but terms. You should write it this way:

```
lengthIs(L2, M), lengthIs(L1, N), M < N/2 -> ...
```

Another typo like mistake: the first clause of lengthIs/2 should read

```
lengthIs([],0).
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to check sizes. Just do it like this:

```
div([],[],[]).
div([A],[A],[]).
div([A,B|T],[A|X],[B|Y]) :- div(T,X,Y).
```

Comment: note that this solutions does not really conform to the OP specification as it does `div([1,2,3,4,5], [1, 3, 5], [2, 4])` instead of `div([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5])`.

Comment: @KonstantinWeitz: this splits `[1,2,3,4,5]` into `[1,3,5]` and `[2,4]`. It splits it into 2 list with the correct lengths, but not the correct *contents*.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't give the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sort of "rabbit and hare" approach.

```
divide(Xs,Ys,Zs) :-
    divide(Xs,Xs,Ys,Zs).

divide(Ls,[],[],Ls).
divide([H|Ts],[_],[H],Ts).
divide([H|Ts],[_,_|Zs],[H|Us],Rs)
    :- divide(Ts,Zs,Us,Rs).
```

The `divide/4` predicate works but stripping both a single element and a double element from the initial list. By the time the second argument gets to the empty list or a list of one element then we are effectively halfway through the list passed as the first argument.

It's effectively `O(n/2)` complexity.

Here's a sample output:

```
?- divide([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],X,Y).
X = [a, b, c, d],
Y = [e, f, g, h] .

?- divide([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],X,Y).
X = [a, b, c, d],
Y = [e, f, g] .
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer,
uses Backtracking a lot, isn't very performant, though.
`append` and `length` are assumed to be predefined:

```
divide(A,B,C):-
    append(B,C,A),
    length(B,B_Length),
    length(C,C_Length),
    (B_Length = C_Length;
        B_Length =:= C_Length +1).
```

Oh, sorry, just have seen that this is sort of a rephrasing of the answer from Philip Whitehouse.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Almost no built-ins:

```
split_list_in_half( Xs , H , T ) :-
  list_length( X , L ) ,
  LL = L - (L // 2) ,
  take_first( Xs , LL , H , T ) ,
  .

list_length( L , N ) :-
  list_length( L , 0 , N )
  .

list_length( [] , N , N ).
list_length( [X|Xs] , T , N ) :-
  T1 is T+1 ,
  list_length( Xs , T1 , N )
  .

take_first( Xs , N , Pfx , Sfx ) :-
  take_first( Xs , N , [] , P1 , Sfx ) ,
  reverse( P1 , Pfx )
  .

take_first( []     , _ , H  , H , []     ).
take_first( [X|Xs] , 0 , H  , H , [X|Xs] ).
take_first( [X|Xs] , N , H1 , H , T      ) :-
  N > 0    ,
  N1 = N-1 ,
  take_first( Xs , N1 , [X|H1] , H , T )
  .
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved head-and-tail iteration, guarding against infinity:

```
split_list_half([A,B|T], Half1, Half2) :-
    split_list_half_([A,B|T], [A,B|T], Half1, Half2, Half2).
    
split_list_half_([], H2, [], _, H2).
% H2D prevents infinity with: split_list_half(L, H1, [c, d]).
split_list_half_([_|T], [H|Sgl], H1, H2D, H2) :-
    split_list_half_dbl_(T, H, Sgl, H1, H2D, H2).

split_list_half_dbl_([], H, H2, [H], _, H2).
split_list_half_dbl_([_|T], H, Sgl, [H|H1], [_|H2D], H2) :-
    split_list_half_(T, Sgl, H1, H2D, H2).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- split_list_half([a,b,c,d], H1, H2).
H1 = [a, b],
H2 = [c, d].

?- split_list_half([a,b,c,d,e], H1, H2).
H1 = [a, b, c],
H2 = [d, e].

?- split_list_half(LF, H1, [d, e]).
LF = [_A, _B, d, e],
H1 = [_A, _B] ;
LF = [_A, _B, _C, d, e],
H1 = [_A, _B, _C] ;
false.
```