# Splitting a list in half

Tags: list, prolog

trying to write code that splits a list in half for even numbers of elements, eg. `split([1,2,3,4],A,B)` would give `A = [1,2]` and `B = [3,4]`.

And behave like Java `list.length()/2` would for odd numbers of elements, so `split([1,2,3,4,5],A,B)` would give `A = [1,2]` and `B = [3,4,5]`.

The closest I can get is something like this, but this isn't quite right, and  only works for even numbers.

```
split(L, A, B) :-
  append(A, B, L),
  length(A, N),
  length(B, N).
```

Comment: You can use a conditional form `( something ; somethingelse )`, to handle the two cases (even and odd).

Comment: Your question is not specific to SWI at all.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8176512/772868).

Answer (score 2):

One way to split a list in half in Prolog is to do so using `append/3` and the `same_length/2` predicates:

```
split(List, Left, Right) :-
    same_length(Left, Right),
    append(Left, Right, List).
split(List, Left, [R|Rs]) :-
    same_length(Left, Rs),
    append(Left, [R|Rs], List).
```

This gives you:

```
| ?- split(L, A, B).
A = B, B = L, L = [] ;
A = [_1038],
B = [_1048],
L = [_1038, _1048] ;
A = [_1038, _1044],
B = [_1054, _1060],
L = [_1038, _1044, _1054, _1060] ;
A = [_1038, _1044, _1050],
B = [_1060, _1066, _1072],
L = [_1038, _1044, _1050, _1060, _1066, _1072] ;
...
```

Comment: Your definition could have better termination properties. Currenty: `split(A,B,C) terminates_if b(A);b(B)` What about `b(C)`?

Comment: @false ah good catch. Definitely an issue with `split(L, A, []).`. I'll think on that one.

Comment: Now the first argument does not influence termination. Where is the progress? (A pity that this is now a dupe...)

Comment: Btw, which toplevel do you use? Sometimes its the _2343243 ugly SWI, and sometimes you have the regular variable names `A, B, C...`.

Comment: @false yeah I was probably hasty with this solution as well. For top level, I usually default to GNU Prolog. I sometimes go to SWI for specific features it provides. In the above, I had access to neither when I ran the code and used SWISH (SWI based). I had to kind of "fake" the semicolon responses since SWISH uses button clicks for "next".

Comment: Just realize that GNU gives for `length(L,2), L = K` the answer `L = [A,B], K = [A,B]``. I always thought it would give `L  = [_A,_B]` as SICStus does. That's why.